# R: using ggplot2 to plot daily dataset subfigure in a time series

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I am trying to plot daily time series using ggplot2.

My questions:

1. how to generate subfigures for daily time series within one figure (i.e., one subfigure has one day (24 h) time series)?
2. how to pull up time series for daytime (08:00 - 17:59) and nighttime (18:00 - 07:59 next day) for plotting?
3. how to set the time tick/label to a 3-hour interval?

Here is the time series looks like:

```
  Sensor    Time
  -0.28     1-25-16 15:00
  -0.27     1-25-16 15:01
  -0.27     1-25-16 15:02
  -0.26     1-25-16 15:03
  -0.25     1-25-16 15:04
  -0.26     1-25-16 15:05
  -0.28     1-25-16 15:06
  -0.28     1-25-16 15:07
  -0.27     1-25-16 15:08
  -0.30     1-25-16 15:12
  -0.31     1-25-16 15:13
  -0.30     1-25-16 15:14
  -0.30     1-25-16 15:15
  -0.31     1-25-16 15:16
  -0.31     1-25-16 15:17
  -0.31     1-25-16 15:18
  -0.31     1-25-16 15:19
  -0.30     1-25-16 15:20
  -0.27     1-25-16 16:00
  -0.28     1-25-16 16:01
  -0.27     1-25-16 16:02
  -0.26     1-25-16 16:03
  -0.26     1-25-16 16:04
  -0.26     1-25-16 16:06
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite tricky to get this right over timezones, multi-years, daylight savings time, etc. I have been doing it a lot. This might help you get started.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

addTimePanelVars <- function(df, stime, tvname="time", tzab = "US/Pacific", fdow = 0) {
    if (tvname != "time") {
        df$time <- df[[tvname]]
    }
    daysecs <- 24 * 60 * 60
    soy <- as.POSIXct(sprintf("%d-01-01 00:00:00", year(stime)), tz = tzab)
    dowsoy <- (as.POSIXlt(soy)$wday - fdow) %% 7
    df$dn <- as.POSIXlt(df$time)$yday
    df$dayFromStart <- as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(df$time, tz = tzab),
         as.Date(soy, tz = tzab), units = "days"))

    df$wn <- trunc(((df$dn + dowsoy)) / 7)
    df$cumwn <- trunc(((df$dayFromStart + dowsoy)) / 7)
    df$date <- as.Date(df$time,tz=tzab)
    df$wkrow <- trunc(df$cumwn / 4)
    df$wkcol <- trunc(df$cumwn %% 4)
    df$dow <- (as.POSIXlt(df$time)$wday - fdow) %% 7
    df$timedy <- (hour(df$time) + minute(df$time) / 60 + +second(df$time) / 3600) / 24
    df$timewk <- df$dow + df$timedy
    df$timehr <- df$timedy*24
    return(df)
}

set.seed(123)
n <- 60 * 24 * 18   # 18 days
tzab <- "US/Pacific"
stime <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-16 15:00:00", tz = tzab)
t <- seq(stime,by=60, length.out = n)
s <- rnorm(n,-0.3,0.02)
df <- data.frame(time = t, sensor = s)
df <- addTimePanelVars(df, stime, tz = tzab)
df$daytime <- ifelse(8 <= hour(df$time) & hour(df$time) < 18, "day", "night")

ggplot(df) +
   geom_point(aes(x = timehr, y = sensor, color = daytime)) +
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = 3 * 0:8) +
   scale_color_manual(values = c(day = "red", night = "blue")) +
   facet_wrap( ~ date )
```

yielding this:

[image]

Not really sure how you wanted to handle the day/night thing. You could subset and display the day and night in different figures for example.

However note the variables in `addTimePanelVars` are also set up to do weekly panels, using `facet_grid(wkrow ~ wkcol)` +